# How to make Insure++ work with boost and g++ 3.4.x

Tags: c++, templates, boost, compilation, compiler-errors

I have linux development environment with g++ 3.4.6, boost 1.47 (latest) and Insure++.
Before I added boost everything was compiling fine. After I tried to compile simple test using boost header only libraries I get this:

```
11/3/11 8:58:37 AM CET: insure g++ -Zstl -Zop /root/.pulse2-agent/data/work/insure/shared/misc/insure.opt -c -DXF_PROFILE  -o temp/linux_x86/test_boost.o -Wall -Werror -pthread -g   -I. -I../../../shared/libs/libtommath-0.41 -I../../../shared/libs/expat-1.95.8/lib -I../../../shared/generic -I../../../shared/test -I../../../shared/libs/sentinel_hasp -I../../../shared/libs/sqlite -I../../../shared/generated -I/boost test_boost.cpp
11/3/11 8:58:37 AM CET: [container_fwd.hpp:64] **PARSE_ERROR**
11/3/11 8:58:37 AM CET:   Parse error.
11/3/11 8:58:37 AM CET: >>     template <class charT, class traits, class Allocator> class basic_string;
11/3/11 8:58:37 AM CET: too few template parameters -- does not match previous declaration
11/3/11 8:58:37 AM CET: [container_fwd.hpp:87] **PARSE_ERROR**
11/3/11 8:58:37 AM CET:   Parse error.
11/3/11 8:58:37 AM CET: >>     template <class T, class Allocator> class vector;
11/3/11 8:58:37 AM CET: too few template parameters -- does not match previous declaration
11/3/11 8:58:37 AM CET: [container_fwd.hpp:88] **PARSE_ERROR**
11/3/11 8:58:37 AM CET:   Parse error.
11/3/11 8:58:37 AM CET: >>     template <class Key, class T, class Compare, class Allocator> class map;
11/3/11 8:58:37 AM CET: too few template parameters -- does not match previous declaration
11/3/11 8:58:37 AM CET: [container_fwd.hpp:89] **PARSE_ERROR**
11/3/11 8:58:37 AM CET:   Parse error.
11/3/11 8:58:37 AM CET: >>     template <class Key, class T, class Compare, class Allocator>
11/3/11 8:58:37 AM CET: too few template parameters -- does not match previous declaration
11/3/11 8:58:37 AM CET: [container_fwd.hpp:91] **PARSE_ERROR**
11/3/11 8:58:37 AM CET:   Parse error.
11/3/11 8:58:37 AM CET: >>     template <class Key, class Compare, class Allocator> class set;
11/3/11 8:58:37 AM CET: too few template parameters -- does not match previous declaration
11/3/11 8:58:37 AM CET: [container_fwd.hpp:92] **PARSE_ERROR**
11/3/11 8:58:37 AM CET:   Parse error.
11/3/11 8:58:37 AM CET: >>     template <class Key, class Compare, class Allocator> class multiset;
11/3/11 8:58:37 AM CET: too few template parameters -- does not match previous declaration
11/3/11 8:58:37 AM CET: Driver: error executing "Run "-Zoicompiler /usr/local/bin/g++" -Zstl -Zop /root/.pulse2-agent/data/work/insure/shared/misc/insure.opt -c -DXF_PROFILE -o temp/linux_x86/test_boost.o -Wall -Werror -pthread -g -I. -I../../../shared/libs/libtommath-0.41 -I../../../shared/libs/expat-1.95.8/lib -I../../../shared/generic -I../../../shared/test -I../../../shared/libs/sentinel_hasp -I../../../shared/libs/sqlite -I../../../shared/generated -I/boost test_boost.cpp"
```

Without Insure++ it compiles just fine. Unlucky I cannot change compiler to new one because of internal project structure.

Any idea what is the real problem and how I can solve this?

/edit

I read somewhere that problems of that kind could be caused by incorrect forward declarations in the boost itself. So I added to my test before boost headers:

```
#define BOOST_DETAIL_NO_CONTAINER_FWD
```

And now it doesn't report any problems, but crashing completely during the compilation:

```
insure g++ -Zstl -Zop /root/x-formation-pk/shared/misc/insure.opt -c -DXF_PROFILE  -o temp/linux_x86/test_boost.o -Wall -Werror -pthread -g   -I. -I../../../shared/libs/libtommath-0.41 -I../../../shared/libs/expat-1.95.8/lib -I../../../shared/generic -I../../../shared/test -I../../../shared/libs/sentinel_hasp -I../../../shared/libs/sqlite -I../../../shared/generated -I/boost test_boost.cpp
Driver: error executing "Run "-Zoicompiler /usr/local/bin/g++" -Zstl -Zop /root/x-formation-pk/shared/misc/insure.opt -c -DXF_PROFILE -o temp/linux_x86/test_boost.o -Wall -Werror -pthread -g -I. -I../../../shared/libs/libtommath-0.41 -I../../../shared/libs/expat-1.95.8/lib -I../../../shared/generic -I../../../shared/test -I../../../shared/libs/sentinel_hasp -I../../../shared/libs/sqlite -I../../../shared/generated -I/boost test_boost.cpp"
makepp: error: Failed to build targets `/root/x-formation-pk/shared/generic/test/temp/linux_x86/test_boost.lob' `/root/x-formation-pk/shared/generic/test/temp/linux_x86/test_boost.o' [2]
```

Comment: Try Valgrind instead of Insure++.

Comment: Insure++ is already integrated with our build environment and continuous integration system on Linux, Windows and Solaris, so I rather have no option to replace it with Valgrind.

Comment: Since your g++ is from 2006, consider an older Boost version. (e.g. 1.37.0 from 2008)

Comment: Unlucky with that version problem was even worse. Except error messages (same as before) I got also crash...

Comment: Did you ask Parasoft about this problem?

Comment: Yes, I'm still waiting for answer. But they are mostly not very fast...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I get the confirmation from Parasoft that I found a bug.
They will try to fix this, issue is already created.